# Turkish dotless i appears as number

Tags: unicode, overleaf

On CV class fortyseconds, when the document is compiled, there is a problem with the dotless i, that it appears as 5. I am compiling the document on Overleaf website, using Chrome.

More clearly when I type `Kayıhan`or `Kay{\i}han` it appears as `Kay5han`.

The class uses utf8:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

all other Turkish characters are fine but only the dotless is, either written as `ı` or `{\i}`.

The class can be found [here](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/forty-seconds-cv/pztcktmyngsk) and the document is as below:

```
\documentclass[
  a4paper, 
%   showframes,
%   maincolor=cvgreen,
%   sectioncolor=red,
%   subsectioncolor=orange
%   sidebarwidth=0.4\paperwidth,
%   topbottommargin=0.03\paperheight,
%   leftrightmargin=20pt
]{fortysecondscv}

% improve word spacing and hyphenation
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

% take care of proper font encoding
%\ifxetex
%   \usepackage{fontspec}
%   \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
%\newfontfamily\headingfont[Path = fonts/]{segoeuib.ttf} % local font
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
%\usepackage[sfdefault]{noto} % use noto google font
%\fi

% enable mathematical syntax for some symbols like \varnothing
\usepackage{amssymb}

% bubble diagram configuration
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\smartdiagramset{
  % defaut font size is \large, so adjust to harmonize with sidebar layout
  bubble center node font = \footnotesize,
  bubble node font = \footnotesize,
  % default: 4cm/2.5cm; make minimum diameter relative to sidebar size
  bubble center node size = 0.4\sidebartextwidth,
  bubble node size = 0.25\sidebartextwidth,
  distance center/other bubbles = 1.5em,
  % set center bubble color
  bubble center node color = maincolor!70,
  % define the list of colors usable in the diagram
  set color list = {maincolor!10, maincolor!40,
  maincolor!20, maincolor!60, maincolor!35},
  % sets the opacity at which the bubbles are shown
  bubble fill opacity = 0.8,
}


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                            PERSONAL INFORMATION
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% profile picture
\cvprofilepic{pics/profile.png}
% your name
\cvname{kay{\i}ıhanğş}
% job title/career
\cvjobtitle{Panda Scientist,\\[0.2em] Panda of the Year}
% date of birth
\cvbirthday{Mar 7, 2019}
% short address/location, use \newline if more than 1 line is required
\cvaddress{Park Ave.~1, 555 555 B-Woods}
% phone number
\cvphone{+86 555 555 555}
% personal website
\cvsite{https://pandascience.net}
% email address
\cvmail{panda@bamboo.cn}
% pgp key
\cvkey{4096R/FF00FF00}{0xAABBCCDDFF00FF00}
% add additional information
% \newcommand{\additional}{some more?}




% add more profile sections to sidebar on first page
\addtofrontsidebar{
    % include gosquare national flags from https://github.com/gosquared/flags;
    % naming according to ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country codes
    \graphicspath{{pics/flags/}}

}

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                         TABLE ENTRIES RIGHT COLUMN
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\makefrontsidebar

\cvsection{Working Experience}
\begin{cvtable}
    \cvitem{currently}{CEO The Panda Way}{Start Up}{Chief executive officer, Head
    developer and yoga ambassador of 'The Panda Way' - A company for pandas from
    pandas that invents, advertises and distributes panda-related content all
    over the world.}
    \cvitem{2015 -- 2018}{Panda Scientist}{Bamboo University}{
        Reasearching the impact of adequate bamboo nutrition compared to
        conventional feeding methods.}
    \cvitem{2010 -- 2015}{Bamboo Broker}{Stock Exchange}{Continuously achieving 
        better bamboo bangs for the buck.}
\end{cvtable}

\cvsignature

\end{document}
```

What do you think the problem might be?

Comment: As always on this site please provide a full (but minimal ) self contained example that others can copy and test on their own.

Comment: Compile your file with `XeLaTeX` on Overleaf.

Comment: **You should have provided MWE.** I have no problem compiling this (`pdflatex`) using the whole template you referred to:
`\begin{document} ı or {\i} \end{document}`

I am using up-to-date MiKTeX. ClearSans font is used (package `clearsans`). I suggest you install some (maybe?) missing packages, update your distribution and available packages, and try again.

Comment: Also, is UTF-8 set as file encoding in your editor?

Comment: I get [this output (click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJC6Q.png). Please, add a minimal example from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`.

Comment: I have made some edits to the question. 

@ferahfeza I did try compiling with XeLatex, but it doesn't change the problem, in addition, removes other Turkish characters.

Comment: @ivankokan I am using Overleaf so UTF-8 is set as default.

Comment: @H.AzizKayıhan That's not a minimal example, because there is no `\begin{document}` and no dotless i to show the problem. Please, update.

Comment: @H.Aziz Kayıhan, no frustration at compiling with `XeLaTeX` on Overleaf. Also I downloaded the codes form Overleaf and compiled on my local machine with `pdfLaTeX`,  there is no problem, as @egreg's pointed out.

Comment: @egreg @H.AzizKayıhan I started the new project on Overleaf from the template, and added `\begin{document} ı or {\i} \end{document}`. The problem really exists. I will check deeply what is going on.

Comment: Using `\listfiles` I found this (among all other differences): `ClearSans.sty    2014/03/16` (Overleaf), `ClearSans.sty    2019/10/16` (my local MiKTeX). Considering https://ctan.org/ctan-ann/pkg/clearsans, changes in 2019 contain this: `Minor corrections to ClearSans.map`. It could be that changes were not so minor. :S

Comment: @egreg hope the question is good now.  Either on Xelatex or pdflatex I can not have the dotless i.

Comment: I don’t know whether all your packages are compatible, but this happened because you’re using legacy 8-bit encodings that have to replace ı with the command `\i` to get documents to work. Going forward, you could switch to an engine that supports Unicode natively, such as LuaLaTeX, and load `fontspec`. It wipes out a lot of technical debt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can now reproduce the issue.

TeX Live 2018 has a buggy version of `smartdiagram.sty` that has the unfortunate effect of changing the meaning of `\i` to `5`.

Overleaf uses TeX Live 2018 and so the buggy `smartdiagram`.

Possible workarounds.

1. Avoid `smartdiagram`.
2. Download `smartdiagram.sty` from CTAN and use the fixed version in the same folder as your project.
3. Save the meaning of `\i` before loading `smartdiagram` and restore it afterwards

   ```
   \let\savedi\i
   \usepackage{\smartdiagram}
   \let\i\savedi
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did avoid the smartdiagram, which solved the problem.

I didn't try the second one but the third one didn' solve it.

Comment: @egreg, When I compile with `XeLaTeX` or  with `LuaLaTeX`on Overleaf, `smartdiagram` does not cause a problem. What is your opinion on this issue?

Comment: @ferahfeza Because the dotless i is not translated into `\i` as it’s done with pdflatex